# Why didn't the Space Shuttle have a launch escape system?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle, launch-escape-system, failure

Since the very beginning of space exploration, rockets had some sort of Launch Escape System (LES). From [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_escape_system), we know that Mercury and Apollo had an escape tower, while Vostok and Gemini had ejection seats.

[image: Apollo LES pad abort test]

*Apollo LES pad abort test (source: wikimedia.org)*

Initially, the Space Shuttle had ejection seats but, (citing Wikipedia)

> were removed once the vehicle was deemed operational

practically leaving it without any LES. What are technical reasons for this choice?

Comment: Part of this is documented in the Wikipedia page on Space Shuttle abort modes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_abort_modes#Ejection_escape_systems

Comment: It seems not to be linked on cited article :(

Comment: Is there any study actually proving STS-51-L crew would've had any chance in surviving, if any escape system was installed / in use on board Space Shuttle Challenger? I mean, even with additional LES engines (on top of Space Shuttle's own), I just don't see it possible to escape that inferno alive. I might be utterly wrong, mind you. But I would like to see some feasibility study first, before suggesting such a system might have saved their lives.

Comment: @TildalWave This is a very hot and sensitive topic in space community. The sad thing is, there are a fair number of reasons to assume, that most of the crew survived the disintegration of the space shuttle. From a physical point of view, it was not even an 'explosion'. Furthermore, it is save to assume, that some crew members may have lived until the pressure compartment hit the water. In a way, a simple parachute could have made a difference here. (For sources, you need to read the original accident report of NASA. Or carefully ask any NASA astronaut - they are all familiar with this topic.)

Comment: My question is why, not what if. I never thought about a that kind of question, since I think has not answer. That suggestion is in your comment @TildalWave, but since someone like you could misread my question, I'm going straight to edit it and remove any reference to Challenger.

Comment: @trapo - No, don't! The reference is fine, but I'd just rephrase the sentence saying "why this fatal choice". It suggests the choice of not having the LES was responsible for the death of Challenger astronauts. I don't see any other issues with your question.

Comment: @trapo If you are asking for the why, you should ask this question in politics or history instead. The answer is somewhere in the policies of the Nixon administration. Build cheap, make it 'profitable' and save as much cash as possible ... (Technical reasons - that's difficult. You would need a fundamentally different design for implementing a proper LES. Any possibility for a proper LES was flushed down the toilet during the early design process of the shuttle during the early 1970s. Space flight was supposed to be 'save' - that's it.)

Comment: @ernestopheles - History of space flights and missions is well within our scope. If we migrated all the questions that extend across boundaries of space exploration (but are also within it) to sites of other sciences, studies, or topics, we might as well migrate all of them. We also have a [meta question](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/270/49) discussing exactly this issue. ;)

Comment: @ernestopheles and you would also migrate 99% of my questions ;)

Comment: @TildalWave Well, trapo is asking for technical reasons. Fair enough, I'll be positively surprised if there was any - I'll stay tuned. I have read so much about this topic, that I could suggest that we talk about what was going on in Washington DC around 1970. US domestic policies is not my strong side, but this is what we would need to discuss here ...

Comment: First comment from @Bart point to right place: technical reasons. 'Why anything else was not realized?' well.. it is another kind of question..

Comment: @ernestopheles - I don't see the reason why answerers wouldn't address political reasoning behind certain decisions as well, if they're able to, it pertains to [space.se] and can be substantiated with facts? Why would that make it off-topic?Granted, we don't want argumentative answers, but I don't really expect an answer here from a politician. And if we get one, and is not substantiated with facts or is trying to spin a political idea on us, I'll be glad to downvote it, flag it as "not an answer" and bash it with counterarguments in the comments, to demonstrate we mean business. ;)

Comment: @ernestopheles - "Furthermore, it is save [sic] to assume." It's never safe to assume, of course. It's also NASA's position that they did not survive the concussion from the initial detonation.

Comment: @DonBranson Fair point. For a long time, it has been NASA's *public* policy that they did not survive the disintegration. Although, and this is rather ironic, even their own reports of 1986 suggested otherwise. Further investigations showed, that the shock (forces) and the lack of ambient pressure were not sufficient to kill the crew. The crew compartment was filmed (on a few frames) leaving the cloud intact. This is as far as it goes, if you ignore the flipped switches on life support equipment. But for the sake of the argument, the actual cause of death could never been determined.

Comment: @ernestopheles - The crew compartment was intact, but that doesn't positively say what happened to the crew inside. They could have been banged around pretty good, even killed, though the cab appeared relatively intact.

Comment: @DonBranson Again true. I must admit, that I do trust the analysis of the NASA guys. I think the commonly cited numbers are [10 to 20G for significantly less than 5 seconds](http://history.nasa.gov/kerwin.html) during break-up of the tank and the shuttle. Combine this with the excellent seats, which were designed to handle the violent vibrations of the SRBs ...

Comment: I guess the complete answer is "budget cuts". Each gram of weight brought to orbit costs a small fortune, and the ejection mechanism isn't quite lightweight.

Comment: Imagine an orbiter in that picture instead of a tiny capsule. You'd need to attach it to basically the rest of the STS to move it anyway. - It was space or bust, unfortunately; no wonder it's retired.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Providing crew escape for all phases of flight of the Space Shuttle, given its design architecture, was simply not practical.  Keep in mind you have up to 7 crew members on two decks.  Keep in mind that the flight regime consists of large ranges of altitude and velocities.  Keep in mind that it would have to cover launch, landing, and several abort modes.  Even the ejection seats used in the early flights couldn't cover the entire flight regime and only worked for the Commander and the Pilot.

**So to answer your question directly:** ejection seats would have only been useful for the crew on the flight deck and then only for a (very) limited part of the total flight regime.

Regarding the use of a LES on the Shuttle:  There were some studies done during early design phases of a separable crew compartment.  Not surprisingly, this added an unacceptable amount of mass to the Orbiter -- at least with the architecture selected.  Of course, this system looked nothing like the LES used on Apollo.  Also, even the LES on Apollo didn't cover all of Apollo's flight regime.

Another interesting fact: the Shuttle was initially designed to allow a shirt-sleeve environment for the astronauts.  This means that prior to STS-26, Shuttle astronauts didn't even wear parachutes (excepting the early qualification flights with ejection seats).  In fact, the seats were not designed to handle astronauts with a parachute.  By "handle," I mean handle the additional weight and volume of a crew member with a parachute and other gear attached.  The seats were modified (and eventually entirely redesigned) for STS-26 and beyond for when the crew members did wear parachutes.

These new chutes were expected to be used for a very limited range of flight regimes/abort modes where the Orbiter could be put into a stable glide configuration that allowed all of the crew to bail out.  This means that you had to ride the solids for at least 2 minutes till they burned out, do some fancy flying to get rid of the External Tank, get the Orbiter into a stable auto-piloted glide, climb down (or over) to the hatch, blow the hatch, extend a pole (see next paragraph), and bail out (x7).  So this really wasn't a launch escape system -- once you light the SRBs, you are committed to at least 2 minutes of powered flight.

Bailing out was to be done with the aid of a crew escape pole.  The pole kept the crew from hitting the leading edge of the wing.  There is some good test footage available here: http://youtu.be/dfVTX25hH-I.  Note that none of this would have helped the astronauts we lost on 51-L or STS-107.

So what is the take-away here?  One (of many) of the big reasons the Shuttle was retired was its lack of provision for crew escape.  All of the likely new manned US systems (government contracted and private) include crew escape for most if not all of the flight regime.  This is one of the reason why most of these systems go with capsules too.

Comment: OTOH, the Buran did have/would have had ejector seats for all crew members.

Comment: The Buran was never manned.  It didn't even have oxygen for crew members.

Comment: Such is [this chap's](http://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20664-cosmonaut-soviet-space-shuttle-was-safer-than-nasas.html) contention.

Comment: Pure conjecture.  Until the system is actually operational, it is nice to say that the crew _would_ have had crew escape at every point.  We will never know.

Comment: @Erik - we have to look at design docs. The SRBs and the full ET made a pre-SRB burnout abort impossible (exhaust from the SRBs, separation loads, tumbling ET).

Comment: But SRBs have less tendency to go BOOM than liquids do as well.  I don't think an ejection seat will help much if the Energia booster goes boom.

Comment: Would it have been so impractical to eject the boosters and the tank prematurely if they malfunctioned during launch? The shuttle itself could have used its powerful engines and aerodynamics to land itself on a runway not far from the launch pad.

Comment: The shuttle carries no propellent or oxidizer for the SSMEs -- assuming you could survive disconnecting with active SRBs and the ET -- which you wouldn't.

Comment: Why couldn't the Shuttle have been blasted clear of the boosters and the Liquid tank? It could then have deployed its own parachute or could even have flown home, perhaps.

Comment: @Dave, any "blast clear" prior to SRB separation would have taken it through the exhaust plume of the SRBs, with unpleasant consequences.  After SRB separation, flying clear of the external tank was possible: these were the "return to launch site" and "transatlantic landing" abort modes.

Comment: @coleopterist [Here's](http://www.buran-energia.com/bourane-buran/bourane-secu-sieges.php) some info about Buran's ejector seats. Seems it only had two. I would think that it would fly most of the time either unmanned or with full crew to a space station. Flying without or with reduced crew is of course a great safety feature.

Comment: What @LocalFluff says about Buran's ejection seats reminds me of the first few qualification flights for the space shuttle, which were done with a crew of two and ejection seats. [Space Shuttle abort modes: Ejection seat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_abort_modes#Ejection_seat) on Wikipedia has details.

Answer (score 3):

The Shuttle just did not have good abort options for most of the flight window. One possible change that would have required being designed in from the beginning would have been an abort system where the entire crew compartment would separate like on an F-111. But it would have added cost and complexity and was not actually designed in.

Comment: Boosters and external tank were ejected anyway. Why not just eject them prematurely if there was a warning that they were failing? Doesn't seem too complex to me if one ejects and lands the entire shuttle instead of just the crew appartment. All launch escape systems are about ejecting from the bad stuff. It would've been facing its protective heatshield towards the exploding stuff ejected.

Comment: What actually destroyed Challenger? Not the SRB burning through. Not the ET burning. It was being pitched into the hypersonic airflow that physically destroyed the airframe.  Possibly killing most of the crew as well.  How do you depart, at hypersonic speeds, while still in appreciable atmosphere from burning SRB's and a tank, when your engines will cut off as soon as you ditch the tank?  The airflow will kill you.

Comment: Why would the main engines cut off during departure from the SRB and external tank? The shuttle had internal fuel for its main engines, or could at least have had, enough to make a landing a minute after launch. All launch escape systems are about departing/ejecting at hypersonic speed in the atmosphere. Maybe it wouldn't have helped Challenger, but I don't see why it would be easier for the SLS to do it from the shuttle stack without the shuttle, than for the aerodynamically shaped and side mounted shuttle itself to do it.

Comment: The Shuttle had zero tankage for SSME's inside it.  All that it would hold internally is the volume left in the plumbing, which I imagine would run out in milliseconds if you were lucky.

Comment: It surely could have been designed to carry enough fuel aboard for an escape landing. Or at least to have jettisoned the SRB's and kept its external tank for a while to do it. Or flown as a glider to a survivable crash landing in the ocean. I fully understand that Challenger had none of those options. But I don't understand why it was designed not to have any of them. Why would it be harder than the real Soyuz one or the Saturn V "Little Joe" test or the upcoming F9 launch launch escape test? Does this deserve an own question?

Comment: @LocalFluff You are describing RTLS. It was only possible in a VERY narrow window.  And NO it could not carry enough fuel to land. Not using SSME's.  They can only throttle down to I think 60ish percent. At that rate, even only one SSME would burn through fuel so fast that there would be payload left on the Shuttle to support it.  This would be a good question as there is lots of reasons.

Comment: @LocalFluff New question asked http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10600/what-is-the-problem-with-aborting-a-space-shuttle-mission

Comment: @geoffc: Your comment about the plumbing inside the Shuttle inspired this question: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35744/26446

Comment: @LocalFluff eventually that kind of ends up being, "why not redesign the shuttle into something like a dyna-soar/Hermes/Starship/Apollo". It's just a lot of changes. Part of the problem was the designer's fantasy of a ship so safe that aborts were barely needed. Of course liquid fuel boosters(shutdown able), or a design without strap on boosters would help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to obtain additional political support for STS, NASA essentially convinced lawmakers to force the Air Force/NRO to replace Titan with Shuttle as the launch vehicle for KH-11 spy satellites and other intelligence hardware which would require launches directly into polar orbit. As both of these programs progessed, weight grew beyond original specifications. The margin was very close already before the increases, and by 1984 NASA was getting ready to do some pretty risky stuff to make good on their promise to launch intelligence payloads--including filament wound boosters, running Block I engines with the original throats/injectors/turbopump impellers at 109% for the entire flight. This should give you an idea of why even 5,000 lbs was completely out of the question for an effective LES. Of course, 51L happened and pretty much the entire military mission was ditched save for a few birds already configured for Shuttle launch, so ironically the same LES that could've easily saved the 51L crew would've ultimately been feasible for the missions STS ended up flying.

Comment: TL;DR: It wouldn't be able to launch the satellites it was contractually built for.

Answer (score 1):

**An effective launch escape system was not incorporated into the STS because of weight considerations that now seem to be both short sighted and even absurd.**

**Possible Escape Systems.**

**1)** An escape ejection capsule system similar to the one used in the **B-58 Hustler** was a possibility. But the ejection capsule weighed several times as much as the seats on the shuttle and were thus not developed.

**2)** Then there is the fact that the entire crew compartment could (should) have been designed to separate as was the case with the **F-111 escape system**. However the system would have once again been in NASA's opinion too heavy.

**3)** verum potest esse penale

The reality is I believe that NASA didn't want to reduce the payload capacity of the STS by including an effective crew escape system. It seems that 50,000lbs of payload to LEO was the 'magic' number NASA wanted and reducing that for the sake of crew safety down to 40,000 to 45,000 pounds of payload to LEO was an undesirable effect of incorporating such an escape system. A system mind you that could have safely protected the crew members from a stationary position on the pad up to a speed of +Mach 2.

Comment: Hmm, Mach 2 out of a maximum of Mach 25, that's certainly very effective for a 10-20% payload reduction….

Comment: Yes, Mach 2 has you covered for something like the first 70-80 seconds of flight. By the time the SRBs provide negligible thrust and are jettisoned, you are already at Mach 4 or thereabouts, and that's around two minutes into the flight.

Comment: The +mach 2 figure assumes that the escape system would be no more robust than those on the B-58 or F-111. Be that as it may I have no doubt (but can not prove) that a very similar system to the B-58s ejection capsule system could have been designed and produced that would be effective at mach numbers s high as 4. But that is something we will never know.

Comment: The question is not about possible escape systems but about why the orbiter didn't have one. The only part of your answer that addresses this seems to be a 'belief' of yours. Do you have any reference to back this up?

Comment: Organic Marble....From Encyclopedia Astronautica, "the shuttle was designed as if it had the inherent operating safety of an airliner. It was not equipped with any provision for crew rescue in case of booster failure during ascent to orbit, or being stranded in orbit, or structural failure during re-entry............ **"But the weight problem also meant that there was no margin for crew safety measures without (to NASA) unacceptable impact to the net payload."** _This is common knowledge_ full article=  http://www.astronautix.com/s/shuttle.html

Comment: The truth is NASA abandoned safety of the crew, not out of payload concerns, but simply out of arrogance.  Had NASA insisted on a 30K LES in addition to the payload capability to launch KH satellites it could have been achieved.    Look at the current SLS booster stack.   In order to increase payload an additional segment was added to the booster stack.   Nothing stopped NASA from building a five segment booster in 1972.    NASA simply failed to ask for a LES to be incorporated because "failure was not an option"  Many engineers at Thiokol will tell you the five segment booster was an option.