# Challenger "What if ?" regarding the SRB plume facing AWAY from the ET

Tags: shuttle-challenger

If the plume on the SRB been facing away from the external tank, could the disaster had been averted ? Wouldn't one SRB exhaust its fuel before the other and as such, would a return to site been necessary ? (Or even attempted)

Comment: Duplicate of [Challenger hypothetical - what if the SRB breach faced outboard?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44239/challenger-hypothetical-what-if-the-srb-breach-faced-outboard)

Comment: Spoiler - the answer is the result would have been the same...