Hypothetical Shuttle tank sep with SRBs firing
Hypothetically, say you had 5 secs warning of a SRB destruction event in the SRB ascent phase of Shuttle. My understanding is that there was no abort possible during the SRB phase, so no RTLS, no ocean water landing, nothing. But say it was a disconnect or blow up situation... would you rather do a tank sep or blow off both SRBs mid burn? Would there be any escape path for Shuttle without collision?

Just a few thoughts: This is during a phase of high G loading. The Tank Separation mechanism is designed to separate with virtually no load. So there is a certain probability, that the mechanism would not even release or selease asymetrically. Also, the Center of gravity would suddenly shift without a way to compensate with the nozzles on the shuttle (only the ones on the SRB)... I see a lot of bad things happening pretty quickly. But I have no sources, so I don't provide an answer...

Potential duplicate question: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21949/could-the-srbs-have-separated-successfully-at-70-seconds-into-flight


...would you rather do a tank sep or blow off both SRBs mid burn?

tl;dr You could not have done either so there is no choice to be made.

The physical reasons why separation of thrusting Solid Rocket Boosters (SRBs) would result in calamity are well explained in answers to this question Could the SRB's have separated successfully at 70 seconds into flight In addition, the SRB separation pushbutton did not even work until 125 seconds after liftoff.





External tank separation at dynamic pressures (QBAR) greater than 10 lbf/ft^2 was prohibited because it could result in collision with the orbiter.


Here is a representative plot of the dynamic pressure during ascent. Note that it remains above 10 lbf/ft^2 throughout SRB thrusting.

The ET sep switch manual position was provided to allow the crew to delay ET separation, not do it early. (In the very early days of the program there was a "fast sep" contingency abort that would shut off the SSMEs and sep the ET when you pushed that button. It was intended for 2-engine-out cases. Later in the program this "fast sep" was automated as part of the effort to implement contingency abort improvements and pushing the button activated the three engine out abort software. Dynamic pressure limits still applied.)

Fast SEP Procedure
a. For two-and three-engines-out CA’s, a Fast ET SEP occurs automatically following MECO Confirmed.
b. Current procedures no longer require it, but a Fast SEP can still be performed manually:

ET SEP switch to MAN.
Depress ET SEP pushbutton

NOTE: Manual Fast SEP is available in MM 102, MM 103, and MM 601.
In MM 103, a manual Fast SEP requires that at least two SSMEs have been recognized as failed.

(MM 102 is liftoff to SRB sep and MM 103 is SRB sep to ET sep)
References:

Main Propulsion System Training Manual
STS-131 L + 2 Day Ascent Performance (SE&I Post Launch Summary)
Flight Procedures Handbook Ascent/Aborts (OI-30)
https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44538/6944
Contingency Abort Training Manual



My understanding is that there was no abort possible during the SRB phase, so no RTLS, no ocean water landing, nothing.

Correct.

would you rather do a tank sep or blow off both SRBs mid burn?

The separation system was not meant to separate a burning SRB. The motors used to move the SRB safely away aren’t that powerful (and amongst other issues this plan), and I think there might be a reasonable chance that the wider bottom of the booster might hit the external tank before it or the SRB had time to move. This would likely explode both the ET and the SRBs, which is near certainly fatal. Even if this scenario didn’t happen, there are plenty of others, such as having to fly through the SRB's exhaust, likely also fatal.
Same SRB exhaust issue as before if you separate the ET. As well, the ET had no separation motor because the Space Shuttle was meant to use RCS to create space between the ET and the Shuttle. Needless to say, an SRB is much more powerful than RCS, and RCS was designed for in space with no thrust being applied. High chance of the space shuttle hitting the orbiter.
I’m going to go with my favorite option being don’t launch that rocket.

Would there be any escape path for Shuttle without collision?

From the Roger’s Commission Report on the Challenger disaster:

There are no corrective actions that can be taken if the boosters do not operate properly after ignition, i.e., there is no ability to separate an Orbiter safely from thrusting boosters and no ability for the crew to escape the vehicle during first-stage ascent.



Neither the Mission Control Team nor the 51-L crew had any warning of
impending disaster.
Even if there had been warning, there were no
actions available to the crew or the Mission Control Team to avert
the disaster.


